# how get address ip of socket in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I want to get IP address through the socket.  My code:

```
      .
      .
      .
int socket_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

adresse_serveur.sin_family      = AF_INET; // le domain
adresse_serveur.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
adresse_serveur.sin_port        = htons(2018);

int taille_de_structure = sizeof(adresse_serveur);
bind(socket_server, (struct sockaddr*)&adresse_serveur, taille_de_structure);
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname

Comment: Sounds like X-Y.  You are trying to get your IP and you think that using a socket is the way to do it.  It isn't.

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to run a TCP server, or just to get your IP address?  Note that your machine will typically have at least two IP addresses (one loopback and one Ethernet), and possibly more if you are multi-homed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socket has been bound to `INADDR_ANY` port `2018`.  It does not have an address more specific than that.  The `INADDR_ANY` indicates that the socket will [`accept`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) connections on any of its interfaces.  It is not connected, so it has no remote address.

Since the socket is apparently intended to be used in a server, you will need to call [`listen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) and then [`accept`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) to get a new connected socket (assuming something actually [`connect`s](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) to it).  The connected socket will have a more specific address bound to both its local and remote ends.  You can get the local address by calling [`getsockname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) and the remote address by calling [`getpeername`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html).

Here is what a TCP server might look like (all error checking is left as an exercise for the reader):

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;

/* create socket */
int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* bind socket to port 2018, any interface */
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
sin.sin_port = htons(2018);
bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));

/* start listening for connections */
listen(sd, 5);

/* accept connections forever */
while (1) {
    struct sockaddr_in remote_sin;
    socklen_t remote_sinlen = sizeof(remote_sin);
    struct sockaddr_in local_sin;
    socklen_t local_sinlen = sizeof(local_sin);

    /* wait for a connection */
    int nsd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&remote_sin, &remote_sinlen);

    /* get the local address of the connected socket */
    getsockname(nsd, (struct sockaddr*)&local_sin, &local_sinlen);

    /* local address is in local_sin.  local_sinlen should still be sizeof(local_sin).
     * remote address is in remote_sin.  remote_sinlen should still be sizeof(remote_sin).
     */

    /* service connection, or fork a child to do it, or whatever... */

    /* close the connection */
    close(nsd);
}
```

Comment: give me the code source please !

Comment: Source for what?  The whole listen and accept, or just the getsockname?  Just Google for "<function> example" with the specific function you are interested in.